# Lua - Waiting for Http Response

Tags: api, post, lua, roblox, pastebin

Note: This is Roblox's version of Lua.

I am working on figuring out how to upload a JSONEncoded table to pastebin. It says I need to acquire a login session key by sending a PostAsync with my dev key, username, and password, and waiting for a response from pastebin with my login session key. Here is my code so far:

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
pasteData = h:UrlEncode(h:JSONEncode(ImgScript))
username = 'USERNAMEHERE'
password = 'PASSWORDHERE'
h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php',
    'api_dev_key=DEVKEYHERE&api_user_name=' .. h:UrlEncode(username) .. '&api_user_password=' .. h:UrlEncode(password),
    2
)

api_user_key = GeneratedUserKeyHere --THIS is what I am after; I don't know how to wait for a response from Pastebin to get this key!
h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php',
    'api_dev_key=' .. api_dev_key .. 'api_option=paste&api_user_key=' .. api_user_key .. '&api_paste_private=1&api_paste_expire_date=N&api_paste_format=lua&api_paste_code=' .. h:UrlEncode(h:JSONEncode(ImgScript)) --ImgScript is the table,
    2
)
```

Comment: This is not normal lua; what application is this inside? you will need to consult their documentation.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that this is Rbx.Lua (Roblox's version of Lua)

Comment: What is wrong? What is being outputted? Please give more information, please. Also, check out http://www.roblox.com/games/290746985/SMessageCleaner-OPEN for an example of how to paste to pastebin

Do you not know how to get the response and interpret it? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I do not know how to wait for the api_user_key to be sent back to me to use to paste.

Comment: Finally, I figured it out! So I had not realized what `PostAsync` essentially was; I thought it only sent data and didn't receive any. So I set `api_user_key` to the login script, as it returned the user key when I gave the dev key and login details. I'll add the working code to the question for anyone who needs this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.
PostAsync not only sends data, but also receives the returned user key, so here is the working script.

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
api_dev_key = 'YourDevKeyHere'
api_paste_code = 'The text of your upload content here'
api_paste_private = '1' --0 public; 1 unlisted; 2 private
api_paste_name = 'The name of your paste here' 
api_paste_expire_date = 'N' --N for never, 10M for 10 minutes, etc.
api_paste_format = 'lua' --The syntax highlighting
api_user_key = ''
api_paste_name = h:UrlEncode(api_paste_name)
api_paste_code = h:UrlEncode(api_paste_code)
username = 'YourUsernameHere'
password = 'YourPasswordHere'

api_user_key = h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php',
    'api_dev_key=' .. api_dev_key .. '&api_user_name=' .. username .. '&api_user_password=' .. password,
    2
)
print(api_user_key) --DON'T DELETE THIS! IT IS ESSENTIAL FOR THE USER KEY TO BE GENERATED!
h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php',
    'api_option=paste&api_user_key=' .. api_user_key .. '&api_paste_private=' .. api_paste_private .. '&api_paste_name=' .. api_paste_name .. '&api_paste_expire_date=' .. api_paste_expire_date .. '&api_paste_format=' .. api_paste_format .. '&api_dev_key=' .. api_dev_key .. '&api_paste_code=' .. api_paste_code,
    2
)
```

Comment: Here is a Roblox model of this that is free to take: http://www.roblox.com/Pastebin-Upload-item?id=302297532